# Error: cannot convert '<unresolved overloaded function type>' to 'function pointer'

Tags: c++, oop, pointer-to-member

```
#include<iostream>
#include<bitset>
#include<string.h>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
#include<math.h>
#include<stdarg.h>


class b {
public:
    b();
    void ef(void(*f)());
};

class d : public b{
public:
    d();
    void print();
};

b::b() {}
void b::ef(void(*f)()) { f(); }

d::d(): b(){}
void d::print() { cout<<"WORKS"<<endl; }

int main() {
    d obj;
    obj.ef(obj.print);
}
```

I have a problem with a derived class method, I would execute `d::print()` as parameter of `b::ef()`, compiling I got this error:

> "error: cannot convert '' to
> 'void (*)()'"

Can you help me to fix it? Thank you

Comment: You can point to the member function as `&d::print`. But member functions have a hidden parameter: a pointer to the object. So the function pointer signature doesn't match.

Comment: Pointer to non-member functions are not compatible with pointers to member functions. The difference is that pointers non-member functions can be called without an object, but pointers to member-functions needs an object. And passing `obj.print` does *not* pass the object only the function (which you really need to use the address-of operator `&` for). I recommend you look into templates or [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function), and [lambdas](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda).

Answer (score 1):

Here's your code, fixed.  But I can see a dozens of things "wrong" with it, in the sense "does what you asked, but not what you (probably) want."

The `print` method needs to act on a `d` object.  But that means the base class has to know about the derived class.  That's awkward.  If the base class had a `virtual print` function, then it could have that passed in, and would call the derived classes override of that virtual function.  But that's not what we have here.

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;

namespace {

class d;

class b {
public:
    b();
    void ef(d&, void(d::*)());
};

class d : public b {
public:
    d();
    void print();
};

b::b() {}

void b::ef(d& dobj, void(d::*f)()) {
    (dobj.*f)();
}

d::d() : b() {}

void d::print() {
    cout << "WORKS\n";
}

} // anon

int main() {
    d obj;
    obj.ef(obj, &d::print);
}
```